# Overwrite clash of clans account

Tags: clash-of-clans

I was playing clash of clans with my first Apple ID.
And now it is town hall 8.
I wanted to transfer it to my new Apple id.
But it shows that my village cannot be overwrite because it is town hall 4 or above.
What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried [deleting all app data](http://www.wikihow.com/Delete-Application-Data-in-iOS), before doing the transfer?

Comment: Yes but still not working

Comment: Related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152992/transfer-clash-of-clans-village-to-another-iphone

Comment: also Related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114951/transferring-clash-of-clans?rq=1

Comment: Check those questions i just linked. See if they answer yours

Answer (score 1):

Yeah Supercell gives you the option to overwrite village over one(same) ID only until its TH4 or less. Once it crosses that, the village gets permanently attached to that particular ID.

However in-Game supercell support does help removing/rectifying such ID issues. So if you like you could give that a try too. (Press the gear button (settings) and go down to help&support tab).

All the Best.

Answer (score -4):

You can do that just renaming keychain.db for a while, during this task.
check this video, its worked for me on ios 9.3.3 .

Comment: Please explain your answer in text instead of relying on a video so that your answer will still be valid even if the video is taken down in the future